# Format(X,D) affecting order by in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I was writing MySQL queries and while formatting the output, I encountered a problem with order by statement. As long as I did not use format, the order by statement worked perfectly but using the format function would result in jumbled output (values were still correct but the order was not correct).

The following query is not the original one but similar:

```
SELECT name, (sal +(sal*com) - max) AS Diff
FROM x NATURAL JOIN y
WHERE x.val1 > y.val2
ORDER BY Diff DESC;
```

The output would be correct i.e. highest difference and associated name first, then the second highest and so on.

Then I formatted it using the following query:

```
SELECT name, FORMAT((sal +(sal*com) - max), 2) AS Diff
FROM x NATURAL JOIN y
WHERE x.val1 > y.val2
ORDER BY Diff DESC;
```

This gave an output with no order.

Can someone please help me understand where I am going wrong and how I can rectify the issue?

Comment: Please show us sample data which demonstrates the behavior of the two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `FORMAT` returns *text*, not a number, so you are sorting your numbers as text, which means that lexicographical rules will happen.  One option, though perhaps not exactly what you want, would be to use `ROUND` instead:

```
SELECT name, ROUND(sal +(sal*com) - max, 2) AS Diff
FROM x
INNER JOIN y
    ON x.val1 > y.val2
ORDER BY Diff DESC;
```

If you need locale specific things like currency symbols or thousands separators, consider handling that in your presentation layer.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you so much. I spent way more time on this than I should have. This will work perfectly for my query. I will accept this answer once time limit has lapsed.